# Where temp tables are located?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

If I create a temporary table using # sign:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM dbo.table
```

Where  is this table located? I can't find this from tempdb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those tables **are** created in your `tempDB` - but the table name might not be exactly as you defined.

In my case, I get:

```
#temp______________________________000000000003
```

Try this:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM dbo.table
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables
```

You should see an entry for that temp table you've just created....

Comment: And to test, say, for existence... OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp')

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a temporary table, SQL Sever adds some additional characters on its name in order to provide a unique system name for it and then it stores it in **tempDB** in the sysobjects table. Even though you can query the temporary table with its logical name, internally is known with the exact name SQL Server has set.

Answer (score 0):

How are you looking for them?
If you do a select you'll get the data.
But the table is only available in the session, just for the user who created it (you can have global temp tables).

They are stored in temp db.

Answer (score 0):

Local temp tables can be created using hash (#) sign prior to table name.

They are visible only in current connection. When connection is dropped its scope ends as well.

It is possible to create and use local temp table with the same name simultaneously in two different connections.

Read More

http://sqlnetcode.blogspot.com/2011/11/there-is-already-object-named-temp-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this issue rose from the fact that if you don't right click and refresh the 'Temporary Tables' folder, SSMS will not show you the temp table immediately.